In the argument of Contingency(Leibnizian Cosmological Argument) can a necessary existent have alternatives?
Hello I've got a question about Leibnizian Cosmological Argument, In the argument can a necessary existent have alternatives? Why yes and why not? And are numbers considered as alternatives to each other like 3 to 7?

Could you please give a reference to and a quote of Leibniz' statement of his argument? Thanks.

It is unclear what you mean by "alternatives" to a necessary existent. That contingents cannot provide a sufficient cause for existence of contingents is a premise of the argument from contingency. One can deny it, but then the argument cannot take off. And what 3 and 7 have to do with it is also obscure. Do you mean that there can be multiple necessary existents? In principle, the argument allows such possibility.

My bad for not being too clear, Im just new to it. So I know this argument for months and I watched a video of William Lane Craig, in the video he was asked why can't universe be necessary rather than god, and he gave an argument like universe could have been made by different collecrion of quarks thats why universe can't be necessary(which I call an alternative to universe), that was his argument. 3 and 7 is about maths being necessary, so numbers are too, but if numbers are alternative too each other, numbers are not necessary or the argument is wrong. Thank you for helping me sir. Conifold

The basic Leibnizian argument has the following steps:
(1)               Every contingent fact has an explanation.
(2)               There is a contingent fact that includes all other contingent facts.
(3)               Therefore, there is an explanation of this fact.
(4)               This explanation must involve a necessary being.
(5)               This necessary being is God. This is the Leibnizian Cosmological Argument sir. The main concept is why is there something rather than nothing. Thank you for helping me sir. Jo Wehler

I guess that when we consider numbers like 3 and 7, we need to differentiate between mathematical necessity and metaphysical necessity.
Mathematical Necessity
Numbers themselves are abstract objects that exist necessarily within the framework of mathematics. The number 3 is not an alternative to the number 7; rather, they are distinct entities with their own unique properties and identities. Each number necessarily exists as part of the mathematical structure, without being interchangeable.
Metaphysical Perspective
From a metaphysical standpoint, numbers do not serve as alternatives to one another in the same way as, say, different possible beings or entities might. Each number has its own existence and identity. In the context of necessary existence, numbers exemplify necessary entities within the realm of mathematics but are not alternatives in the sense relevant to the cosmological argument.

I appreciate you sir, can I ask you about this argument through comments, I don't wanna add new question because what I am gonna ask is pretty much the same topic, do you mind if I ask you from here sir?
